# Question 1: Using only the language of high school linear algebra, how does one find the generators of SU(2)?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics

My final objective is to try to understand the business of roots and weights in group theory.

I want to focus on SU(2). I'm doing this because abstractions are a bit hard for me right this minute.

I'm going to think of [SU(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) very simply as the group of 2 x 2 matrices that are [unitary and have determinant 1](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpecialUnitaryGroup.html). This is to keep things as simple as possible.

The Lie Algebra is [generated by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Lie_algebra_2)

$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & i \\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 
i &  0 \\
0 & -i 
\end{pmatrix}$

I'm not clear on how these generators come about.

This could be good to know.

One can then deduce a root from this somehow, but I am getting ahead of myself. I am not yet sure how this all works.

I'm inclined to believe it should be simple.

Using only the language of high school linear algebra, how does one find the generators of SU(2)?

**
The below is just some stuff I have tried, very likely wrong but might be worth commenting on at least it will guide me a but.

I have now performed some numerical experiments on this, can someone let me know if I am anywhere close?

Someone copy modify and try this code and let me know.. . .

```
(* Step 1: Define g(t) as a 2x2 matrix *)

g[t_] := {{a[t], b[t]}, {-Conjugate[b[t]], Conjugate[a[t]]}}

(* Step 2: Compute the anti-Hermitian matrix X *)

X = -I * MatrixLog[g[t]]

(* Step 3: Diagonalize X to obtain its eigenvectors *)

eig = Eigensystem[X];
eigV = eig[[2]];

(* Step 4: Construct the generators of su(2) *)

(* Step 4a: Construct the first generator T1 *)
T1 = (1/2) * (eigV[[1]] * ConjugateTranspose[eigV[[1]]] - eigV[[2]] * 
ConjugateTranspose[eigV[[2]]]);

(* Step 4b: Construct the second generator T2 *)
 Y = I * X; (* Define Y = iX *)
T2 = (1/(2*I)) * (eigV[[1]] * ConjugateTranspose[eigV[[2]]] - eigV[[2]] * 
ConjugateTranspose[eigV[[1]]]);

(* Step 4c: Construct the third generator T3 *)
T3 = (1/2) * (eigV[[1]] * ConjugateTranspose[eigV[[1]]] + eigV[[2]] * 
ConjugateTranspose[eigV[[2]]]) - (1/2) * IdentityMatrix[2];

(* Step 5: Verify that the generators satisfy the commutation relations *)

(* Compute the commutators of the generators *)
Comm[T1, T2]
Comm[T2, T3]
Comm[T3, T1]

(* Step 6: Verify that the generators form a basis for the Lie algebra *)

(* Compute the determinant of the matrix formed by the generators *)
Det[Transpose[{Flatten[T1], Flatten[T2], Flatten[T3]}]]

(* The determinant should be non-zero for the generators to form a basis *)
```

Below is some other embryonic Mathematica experimental code where I try to delineate between SU(2) and su(2)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @JesseMadnick Thank you. Editing out that remark now.

Comment: Perhaps you mean generates the *Lie algebra* $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ of the Lie group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$---for which the given matrices are the standard generators---rather than the Lie group itself.

Comment: See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Lie_algebra_2

Comment: Although Lie groups (such as $\mathrm{SU}(2)$) are typically not vector spaces, their Lie algebras always are.  In this case, the Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, which is a $3$-dimensional vector space consisting of trace-zero, anti-Hermitian $2 \times 2$ matrices.  Your "generators" form a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.  Note also that your generators are not elements in $\text{SU}(2)$.  In the physics literature, the distinction between $\text{SU}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is sometimes not made clear, but they are really quite different.

Comment: @TravisWillse yes, I should fix this too

Comment: Hi y'all, I have elected to embarrass myself yet again by posting an answer. It is more of a show of effort and a template waiting to be modified than an answer. Please check it out at your convenience

Comment: I have now added the code to things I have tried in the question, as it quickly got a downvote when I put it up meaning as I anticipated that it has some problems.

Comment: What is "high school linear algebra"?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Well, I was guessing that "high school linear algebra" would be a fun way of saying using very little advanced mathematical terminology and just computation.

Answer (score 0):

Someone, please edit this.

My previous answer was not even adequate. This is my second attempt.

Here goes.

SU(2) the group and su(2) the algebra are different.

$G \in SU(2)$ satisfies

\begin{pmatrix} 
\alpha & - \bar{\beta} \\
\beta & \bar{\alpha} 
\end{pmatrix}

such that $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$

If the group elements in SU(2) are parameterized,

There is such a thing as Lie group- Lie algebra correspondence

The correspondence says there is a relationship between the tangent space of the Lie group at the identity element and the lie algebra of the group.

It would then seem that for some parameterization, oh God help me

\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} & - e^{i \phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
e^{-i \phi}sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} & \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}

So

$X = i \frac{d}{d \theta} G|_{\theta -> 0, \phi -> 0}$

$Y = i \frac{d}{d \theta} G|_{\phi -> 0, \phi -> 0}$

$Z = \frac{1}{2 i}(X.Y - Y.X)$

I want to also believe that there is a correspondence between $G \in SU(2)$ and $g \in su(2)$

$g = Log(G)/i$

$G = Exp(t g)$

t is a parameter.

Comment: I feel there is an easier way to get there. $SU(2)$ comprises matrices preserving a complex inner product $\langle,\rangle$ on $\mathbb{C}$. So $\langle gv,gw\rangle = \langle v,w \rangle$. Taking $g=\operatorname{exp}(tX)$ for $X \in \mathfrak{su}(2)$ and differentiating at $t=0$ gives $\langle Xv,w\rangle + \langle v,Xw \rangle =0$ or in other words $X$ is anti-Hermitian and then the basis you mention is just a natural basis to choose for the tracefree anti-Hermitian matrices. This is perhaps not "high school" level but is

Comment: Yes, this is a very effective strategy. I'm going to be implementing this in code now.

Comment: The missing words at the end of my comment were supposed to be: relatively straightforward