# Question 2: What is a plain English and highschool level linear algebra recipe to finding the roots and weights given su(2) generators?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, physics

You are given the generators of su(2).

You want to get the roots and weights.

What are the steps?

Using plain English. To me, the idea looks as such

- Write the Cartan generators
- Find  the eigenvalues
- These are the root
- Weights have something to do with the normalized eigenvectors corresponding to the roots

How close? How is it done in plain English and high school-level math

Comment: Answers here written have a very high probability of being answered in English. So, what does plain english signify here ?

Comment: What is the point of "Question 2"?

Comment: Oh, I see; here's Question 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4692667/104041

Comment: @An_Elephant It's just a way of speaking. It means easy, and mostly in words.

Comment: @Shaun I split a question about roots and weights in 2 parts

Comment: Neither $SU(2)$ nor Cartan generators are covered in high school algebra. I didn't learn about eigenvalues or eigenvectors in high school either, despite being in advanced math classes, but I can imagine them being covered. But still, it is rather hard to give high school algebra answer to a beyond-high-school algebra question.